# "Object doesn't support this property or method" error - JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a problem regarding to growl notification in jquery. I have this error in IE (which I know not the best choice to test your code but just to your error in javascript) "Object doesn't support this property or method".

**notifyBidding.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    addNotice();
    setTimeout(function(){
    addNotice();
    },4000);        
$('#growl')
    .find('.close')
    .live('click', function(){
        $(this)
            .closest('.notice')
            .animate({
            border: 'none',
            height: 0,
            marginBottom: 0,
            marginTop: '-6px',
            opacity: 0,
            paddingBottom:0,
            paddingTop:0,
            queue:false
            },1000, function(){
                $(this).remove();
        });
        });
});

function addNotice(){
$('#growl')
.append($('<div id="bidTo"></div>').html($('<img id="bg2" src="notification.png" width="250" height="75"></img><p id="tag2">This item is about to end</p><img id="dp2" src="temporary.jpg"/><p id="bidTime" style="font-family:arial narrow; font-size:12; color:rgb(171,14,21); text-transform:uppercase; position:absolute; top:25px; left:85px"><b>about to end</b></p>')))
.hide()
.appendTo("#growl")
.fadeIn(1000)
.fadeOut(3000)

$('#bidTo').contents().unwrap();

}
```

**welcome.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design2.css"/>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src='script.js'></script>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="notification.js"></script>
    <script src="notifyBidding.js"></script>

<body>

<a id='imgCart' href='#'></a>


<div id='notification' >
    <img id='bg' src='notification.png' width='1110' height='65'></img>
    <p id='tag'>There are still &nbsp;&nbsp; in your shopping cart</p>
    <p id='noToPay'>5</p>
</div>

<div id='growl'></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/live/ is deprecated As of jQuery 1.7 check your jquery version.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't exist. It was, however, removed entirely at some point (I think version 1.9), so they do need to include the version of jQuery they're using.

Comment: What is the line where you have this error?
Use `.on` instead of `.live`, `.live` is **deprecated**

Comment: how about the function .validate? Is it also deprecated? not working to me also. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put your `<script>` in the `<head>` section or before closing `</body>` tag of your page.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design2.css"/>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src='script.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="notification.js"></script>
    <script src="notifyBidding.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also, since you're using jQuery version `1.11` and `.live()` has been removed in version `1.9`, you need to use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead , so you can change:

```
$('#growl').find('.close').live('click', function(){ .....
```

to:

```
$('#growl').find('.close').on('click', function(){ .....
```

Besides that, if your `scripts.js` utilize jQuery or other plugins, you must include it after you've included jQuery and other plugins.

Last note is that you just need to include jQuery once instead of twice like what you're doing at this moment.

Comment: That's all your honour ;)